# Passing C# object to JScript

Tags: c#, jscript

I have this working:

```
Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine engine = Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine.CreateEngine();
string js = "15+10";
var result = Microsoft.JScript.Eval.JScriptEvaluate(js, engine);
```

Now I want to pass some objects from C#. Is it possible?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: the vsaengine class is marked as obsolete in VS2005 with no replacement. There are a number of projects around that process C# at runtime

Comment: @SimonHalsey I am sorry. I am new in C#. What is that mean?

Comment: It means you shouldn't use it. C# isn't really designed as a runtime scripting language. You're better of using something like JavaScript.

Comment: @SimonHalsey I really need this thing. I want to use it like Expression Parser.

Comment: a quick googling comes up with [jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/) & [Javascript .NET](http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/). Any of these suit your needs?